# Grid lay-out in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I've got a webpage in which I want to add a table.
The table contains 6 columns where the first column is about 2.5 times wider than the other columns.

My idea was to make a grid row with 4 3-width columns, after which I would devide the second, third and fourth columns in two, or something like that..

Is there a better/cleaner way to style my columns the way I want it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the grid and some custom styles.

```
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="one-fifth"></div>
    <div class="one-fifth"></div>
    <div class="one-fifth"></div>
    <div class="one-fifth"></div>
    <div class="one-fifth"></div>
</div>
<style>
    .one-fifth
    {
        width: 20%;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }

    @media (max-width:767px)
    {
        .one-fifth
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: the media query is needed if you want it to be optimized for mobiles. if not, neglect it.